# How to create BigQuery tbl using dplyr

Tags: r, google-bigquery, dplyr

(edited to attempt to make a reproducible example)

I'm trying to connect to BigQuery via dplyr (and dependencies) and I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
require(dplyr)   #installed from cran
devtools::install_github("assertthat")
devtools::install_github("bigrquery")
require(bigrquery)

billing_project = "omitted"

sql <- "SELECT year, month, day, weight_pounds FROM natality LIMIT 5"
query_exec("publicdata", "samples", sql, billing = billing_project)

# returns
# Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
# year month day weight_pounds
# 1 1969     1   2      8.999270
# 2 1969     1  15      8.375361
# 3 1969     1  27      9.124933
# 4 1969     1   9      6.000983
# 5 1969     1  25      7.561856

bq_db = src_bigquery("publicdata","samples", billing=billing_project)
bq_db

# returns
# src:  bigquery [publicdata/samples]
# tbls: github_nested, github_timeline, gsod, natality, shakespeare, trigrams, wikipedia


tri=tbl(bq_db, "trigrams")

# returns
# Error in UseMethod("sql_select") : 
# no applicable method for 'sql_select' applied to an object of class "bigquery"
```

It is that last error that I'm having a problem with.

I originally installed dplyr from cran, and it is at version 0.1.3. The bigrquery package is installed from github via devtools, and it is at 0.1.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bigrquery_0.1 dplyr_0.1.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1.0.99 devtools_1.5        digest_0.6.4        evaluate_0.5.3      httpuv_1.3.0       
 [6] httr_0.3            jsonlite_0.9.7      memoise_0.2.1       parallel_3.1.0      Rcpp_0.11.1        
[11] RCurl_1.95-4.1      stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.0         whisker_0.3-2
```

I also tried with this:

```
sql_q <- "SELECT year, month, day, weight_pounds FROM natality LIMIT 5"
tri=tbl(bq_db, sql(sql_q))
# results in
# Error in UseMethod("qry_fields") : 
#  no applicable method for 'qry_fields' applied to an object of class "bigquery"
```

Comment: Could you please make the example a little more reproducible? i.e. how did you install and load bigrquery and dplyr?

Comment: hopefully the edit helps. 1st attempt was poor form on my part

Comment: The first thing I'd try is dplyr from github.

Comment: What's the 2nd thing you'd try? Same error as before. Dplyr installed with devtools::install_github("dplyr") and sessionInfo() now shows 

other attached packages:
[1] bigrquery_0.1 dplyr_0.2    

(is this question still good for stackoverflow? or should I move over to github?)

Comment: Best to move to github please.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
df <- tbl_df(query_exec(sql, project, max_pages = Inf))
```